# When should I use RedirectBase in apache2.conf?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

After reading this page (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html), I get very confused on which situations I should use a `RedirectBase` directive.

For example, for this point:

> The original request, and the substitution, are underneath the DocumentRoot (as opposed to reachable by other means, such as Alias).

Does that mean if I have a folder like /abc/def in my web server folder, and I am directly using the whole rewrite module in the "`Directory /abc/def`" block, I don't need to use the `RedirectBase` directive?

Also, if I am trying to rewrite all URLs except `cons.html` to the page `cons.html`, like in the following block of code 
`<Directory /abc/def/>
RedirectEngine on
RedirectCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^cons.html$
RedirectRule (.*) conf.html
</Directory /abc/def/>`
Do I need to use the `RedirectBase` directive?

Thanks

Comment: No and yes, respectively. If you are putting your rewritten URLs based from server root, you don't need `RewriteBase`.

Comment: So will it also rewrite the URL in `RewriteCond`? Like in the given block will it help me add the `/abc/def/` before `cons.html`? Is it valid to use `RedirectCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^cons.html$` to redirect any page that is not `/abc/def/cons.html` to that page?

Comment: And why does this not work?
`<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/s/([0-9]+)$ /serviceQuick.php?svhid=$1
</Directory>`

Comment: Because a rewriterule with "^/" can never work in htaccess. It's got nothing to do with RewriteBase.

Comment: It would be clear if you needed it or not, because your substitution would go to the wrong filename/URL.

Comment: @covener but the problem is that if I get the wrong one I wanna know whether I need that to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The manual is pretty clearhere.

This directive is required when you use a relative path in a substitution in per-directory (htaccess) context unless either of the following conditions are true:

- The original request, and the substitution, are underneath the
  DocumentRoot (as opposed to reachable by other means, such as Alias).
- The filesystem path to the directory containing the RewriteRule,
  suffixed by the relative substitution is also valid as a URL path on 
  the server (this is rare).
- In Apache HTTP Server 2.4.16 and later, this directive may be omitted    when the request is mapped via Alias or mod_userdir.